# How to copy data from a datable to dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Hi i am trying to copy data from one generic table to a typed datable.
i am using this code

```
    Dim dsLocal As New LocalDataset
    Dim dtLocals As New LocalDatasetTableAdapters.Tickets_MessagesTableAdapter

    dsLocal.Tickets_Messages.Merge(dt)
    dtLocals.Update(dsLocal.Tickets_Messages)
```

where the dt is the source datable. but the data are not saved. what am i missing?

Comment: What is the `RowState` of each `DataRow` in `dt`?  If it's `Unchanged` then there's nothing to save.

Comment: what do you mean row state. the dt is populated from a query . and i need to import all these results to the types dataset. can you please explain to me what should i do

Comment: I'm asking you for more information so that I can help so to not give me the information and then ask me to help is making it LESS likely I'll help, not more.  I asked you what the `RowState` of each `DataRow` is.  Did it not even occur to you to throw `RowState` and `DataRow` into a Google search and see if anything relevant turns up?  I'm here to help but I don't expect you to turn your brain off and stop thinking.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your help. what i don't understand is that why should i check for the row state of dt? dt is the result of a query. should i use merge to input this result to the dataset or something else. After merge i can see the records in the dataset (in memory) the problem is how should i commit them in the db

Comment: @jmcilhinney i am looping all row from the dsLocal.Tickets_Messages (not dt) and set rowstate as added. is it normal procedure?